# How can i find the middle of a Hexgrid?

Tags: c#, godot

So ive created a code which will use my Standard hexagon Node from Godot and istance it for a given size into a hexgrid, now i wanted to find the exact middle of this Hexgrid to position my player there eg. move the Nodes along the X and Z axis to the standard position of the map 0,0,0.

I thought the exact middle of the Hexgrid is Axis X - Size of the X Axis / 2, Axis Z - Size of the Y Axis / 2.
But this just doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions on how to finde the middle of the Hexgrid and how to move it along the axis?
The Code for the middle looks like this:

```
public void GenerateGrid()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSize.Y; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridSize.X; x++)
            {
                
                Vector3 newPos = GetPositionFromCurrentHex(new Vector2(x, y));
                Node3D generator_scene = (Node3D) ResourceLoader.Load<PackedScene>(tilePath).Instantiate();
                generator_scene.Position = new Vector3(newPos.X - (gridSize.X / 2.0f), newPos.Y, newPos.Z - (gridSize.Y/ 2.0f));
                if (isFlatTopped)
                {
                    generator_scene.RotateY(Mathf.DegToRad(90));
                }
                AddChild(generator_scene);

            }
        }
    }
```

And for the Calculation of the Hexgrid:

```
public Vector3 GetPositionFromCurrentHex(Vector2 coordinate)
    {
        float col = coordinate.X;
        float row = coordinate.Y;
        float width;
        float height;
        float xPos;
        float yPos;
        bool shouldOffset;
        float horizontalDistance;
        float verticalDistance;
        float offset;
        float size = outerSize;


        if (!isFlatTopped)
        {
            shouldOffset = (row % 2) == 0;
            width = Mathf.Sqrt(3) * size;
            height = 2f * size;

            horizontalDistance = width;
            verticalDistance = height * (3f / 4f);

            offset = (shouldOffset) ? width / 2 : 0;

            xPos = (col * (horizontalDistance)) + offset;
            yPos = (row * verticalDistance);
        }
        else
        {
            shouldOffset = (col % 2) == 0;
            width = 2f * size;
            height = Mathf.Sqrt(3f) * size;

            horizontalDistance = width * (3f / 4f);
            verticalDistance = height;

            offset = (shouldOffset) ? height / 2 : 0;
            
            xPos = (col * (horizontalDistance));
            yPos = (row * verticalDistance) - offset;
        }


        return new Vector3(xPos, 0, yPos);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on how you define center in different cases, for example

- Is your hexgrid flat top or pointy top?
- Is the topmost row of your hexgrid also leftmost or not (offset of rows)
- Do you expect your "center" of the hexgrid to be also center of an hexagon, or it can be a point along edge of some hexagons.

If the number of rows and columns are odd, you can get away with calculating the coordinates of 4 corner points (topleft, topright, botleft, botright) and average them. If your grid is pointy-top this is also center of the middle hexagon, if your grid is flat-top it is on the edge between two hexagons.

Comment: I can use flat top as well as pointy top which is defined by the if condition "isFlatTopped". The topmost row is not leftmost. It would be nice to be the center of an hexagon as well

Thanks in advance!